# How to sum up the duplicated value while keep the other columns?

Tags: r, sum, duplicates, aggregate

I have a dataset like this

```
    V0  V1  V2  V3   X     Y  
#1  1   A   21  31   123   12
#2  2   A   21  31   245   24
#3  3   B   22  32   234   25
#4  4   C   23  33   190   30
#5  5   C   23  33   210   20
```

So there are duplicated value in V1, V2 and V3; and I would like to create a dataset like this, which sum up X and Y respectively, by V1-V3

```
    V1  V2  V3   X     Y    V
#1  A   21  31   368   36   1,2
#2  B   22  32   234   25   3
#3  C   23  33   400   50   4,5
```

I was trying "aggregate" as below, but have no idea how to do it with both X and Y together, and at the same time, keep V2 and V3 as the original value, instead of sum them. And how can I put the value in V0 within the same group (V1) in another new variable.

```
 df.sum <- aggregate(X~V1,data=df,FUN=sum)
```

I try to merge the "df.sum" with "df" by "V1" afterwards, but it turns out that all the duplicated value were merged as well.

Any suggestion? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or by `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(V1,V2,V3) %>% summarise(X_sum=sum(X), Y_sum= sum(Y))
# Or as suggested, you could also do:
df %>% group_by(V1,V2,V3) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))

#Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
#Groups: V1, V2
#
#  V1 V2 V3 X_sum Y_sum
#1  A 21 31   368    36
#2  B 22 32   234    25
#3  C 23 33   400    50

# data
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(21L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 23L), 
    V3 = c(31L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 33L), X = c(123L, 245L, 234L, 
    190L, 210L), Y = c(12L, 24L, 25L, 30L, 20L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "X", "Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Regarding the updated data, you could do something like:

```
df %>% group_by(V1,V2,V3) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum, toString), X, Y, V0) %>%
  select(-V0_sum,
         -X_toString,
         -Y_toString)
# you get
#   V1 V2 V3 X_sum Y_sum V0_toString
# 1  A 21 31   368    36        1, 2
# 2  B 22 32   234    25           3
# 3  C 23 33   400    50        4, 5

# data
df <- structure(list(V0 = 1:5, V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(21L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 23L), 
    V3 = c(31L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 33L), X = c(123L, 245L, 234L, 
    190L, 210L), Y = c(12L, 24L, 25L, 30L, 20L)), .Names = c("V0", 
"V1", "V2", "V3", "X", "Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Why not `summarise_each`? (`mydf %>% group_by(V1, V2, V3) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))`)

Comment: @AnandaMahto, Sure it equally works.  But like to assign customized column names.

Comment: i got "Error in empty(.data) : could not find function "%>%"" after running this. any idea what's going wrong? And I also edited my question, adding a merging of variable (V0).  Thank you!

Comment: @cyrusjan, You need to load `library(dplyr)`

Comment: Aha, i loaded plyr instead.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track. Just do:

```
aggregate(. ~ V1 + V2 + V2, mydf, sum)
#   V1 V2 V3   X  Y
# 1  A 21 62 368 36
# 2  B 22 32 234 25
# 3  C 23 66 400 50
```

---

You can also do this in many other ways. For example, here's an approach using "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = list(V1, V2, V3)]
```

Comment: Or spinning it around - `aggregate(cbind(X,Y) ~ ., data=dat, FUN=sum)`